# react-native-reanimated Missing File Error

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]

I am trying to compile my React Native application with Expo and for some reason, I keep encountering this issue with react native reanimated. I have removed and installed this package several times, and nothing is working. I even tried removing that line in the appropriate file within the node_modules folder, but it appears that deleting the line had no effect, as this error continues to pop up. I tried changing versions of react-native-reanimated as well. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a solution to this?

[image]

Comment: how are you installing react-native-reanimated?

Comment: @GauravRoy I used both expo install react-native-reanimated and yarn install react-native-reanimated